# How to convert join DB raw with find_in_set?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to convert the following query into laravel query but facing an issue with the 0 value as having to pass join's argument as a column so it does not allow me to add 0 as a number.

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(contracts.contract_code) as code , `callout_rotta`.* from `callout_rotta` 
inner join `contracts` on FIND_IN_SET(contracts.id, callout_rotta.contract_id) > 0 
inner join `users` as `engineer` on `callout_rotta`.`engineer_id` = `engineer`.`id` 
where `callout_rotta`.`deleted_at` is null group by `callout_rotta`.`id`
```

following way I am trying to join in laravel query but showing the error of 0 as 0 is not a column.

```
->Join('contracts', DB::Raw("FIND_IN_SET(contracts.id, callout_rotta.contract_id)"), '>', 0 )
```

I tried advanced query as following

```
->join('contracts', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('contracts.id', '=', DB::Raw("FIND_IN_SET(contracts.id, callout_rotta.contract_id) > 0 "));
                })
```

but not getting proper result as passed contract column in join is there any way where I don't need to pass field id or operator in join query for this case

Comment: You mix raw and regular syntax which is not correct... use [Advanced Join Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses) (`$join->on`). PS. `FIND_IN_SET` output may be used itself, without compare to zero.

Comment: tried but not working not showing correct records in this case.

Comment: *tried but not working* Add this attempt to the question text as an update.

Comment: I have update the code I tried please review and help if I am missing any thing here.I know the reason of wrong result but have no solution for correct result.

Comment: Test single `$join->on(DB::Raw("FIND_IN_SET(contracts.id, callout_rotta.contract_id)"))`

Comment: It is converting as following.
inner join `contracts` on FIND_IN_SET(contracts.id, callout_rotta.contract_id) = `` 
show showing an error:
Unknown column '' in 'on clause'

Comment: o_O your complete join clause looks like this: ```->join('contracts', function ($join) { $join->on(DB::Raw("FIND_IN_SET(contracts.id, callout_rotta.contract_id)")) } )``` ?

Comment: Yes exact same

->join('contracts', function ($join) {
                    $join->on(DB::Raw("FIND_IN_SET(contracts.id, callout_rotta.contract_id)"));
                })

Comment: Test also this form: ```$join->on(DB::Raw("FIND_IN_SET(contracts.id, callout_rotta.contract_id)", '>', '0'))```

Comment: your query shows = Unknown column '' in 'on clause'

then tried following also shows an error
->join('contracts', function ($join) {
                    $join->on(DB::Raw("FIND_IN_SET(contracts.id, callout_rotta.contract_id)"), '>', '0');
                }) 
Unknown column '0' in 'on clause

Comment: Use zero without quotes: `$join->on(DB::Raw("FIND_IN_SET(contracts.id, callout_rotta.contract_id)", '>', 0))`?

Comment: That's an issue I was using 0 as number but it says 0 column not found. that's the issue we can't pass rather than column name there

Comment: It's a correct sysntax of mysql but not working in laravcel query format

Comment: Maybe `DB::Raw("0")`? PS.Do you know some site with Laravel online fiddle?

Comment: It's working now with following.
->join('contracts', function ($join) {
                    $join->on(DB::Raw("FIND_IN_SET(contracts.id, callout_rotta.contract_id)"), '>', DB::Raw("0"));
                })